# Show echo inside a DIV

Tags: php, html, echo

I'm having a very annoying issue and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. It has (again) something to do with loading in a page into a DIV.

I have made a form which can be used to update information into a database. This form and PHP code is in one file and is being loaded in one DIV. When I visit the page which is loaded into the DIV itself, everything is working fine and the database is being updated as it should.

Though, when the page is loaded into the page. When I press submit nothing happens. What I want to happen is that the echo, which is either "Success!" or "Error!" is being displayed in the same DIV as the page is loaded into. This is my code, I hope someone can help! *some variables are in Dutch, excuse me for that.*

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))  {

                     include "database.php";
                     session_start();

                     $id = $_POST['id'];
                     $titel = $_POST['titel'];
                     $text = $_POST['text'];
                     $categorie = $_POST['categorie'];
                     $auteur = $_SESSION['sess_loginnaam'];
                     $laatst_aangepast = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

                     $sql="UPDATE paginas SET id='$id', titel='$titel', text='$text', categorie='$categorie', auteur='$auteur', laatst_aangepast='$laatst_aangepast' WHERE id='$id'";
                     $result=mysql_query($sql);
                     if($result){
                     echo "Success!";
                     ?>
                     <META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" content="2;URL=index.php">
                      <?php }
                     else {
                         echo "Mislukt!";
                     }
                 }

                 else {

                     include "database.php";
                     $id = $_GET['id'];
                     $sql="SELECT * FROM paginas WHERE id='$id'";
                     $result=mysql_query($sql);
                     $rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);

                     <form name="form1" method="post" action="">
                     ID:
                     <input name="id" type="text" id="id" value="<? echo $rows['ID']; ?>"     size="2"></div> Titel:
                     <input name="titel" type="text" id="titel" value="<? echo $rows['titel']; ?>" size="50%"> Categorie: <select name="categorie"><option    value="Paginas">Pagina's</option>
                     </select>
                     Tekst:
                     <textarea name="text" type="text" id="text" rows="31" cols="79"><?                echo $rows['text']; ? ></textarea>
                     <button type="submit" name="submit">Edit!</button>
                     </form>
```

And here is the code I use to load this page into the DIV:

```
$("#edit").on('click',function(){
$('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));
  });
```

So how can I manage to display the echo into the same DIV? :)

Answer (score 0):

`$.load` is equivalent to `$.get` whereas your php code detect `$_POST`, that's way there is no response.

You can change your js code to

```
$("#edit").on('click',function(){
    $.post($(this).attr('href'), YOUR_FORM_DATA_HERE, function(data){
        //update your page here with response
    });
});
```

[See $.load - jQuery Doc](http://api.jquery.com/load/)